# How to pass arguments to an alias?

Tags: alias

I'd like to set up an alias `push`, which would translate into `git push origin ARG1:ARG1`.

For instance, from the command line, i'd like to `push A B` and get that translated to `git push origin A:B`

How should my alias export statement look for this to work?

Comment: For what shell and/or operating system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aliases to automatically pass default arguments to the original command.

So, in your case, you can alias `git push origin` with `push` if you need.
But you can not achieve what you are trying to do. You should use bash functions instead.

Comment: Something like this `function push { git push origin $1:$1; }`?

Comment: do you want to use $2 (for B?)